# Joint configuration issues with Schunk Powerball-MoveIt integration

Tags: ros, moveit, schunk, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am currently attempting to integrate the Schunk Powerball manipulator with MoveIt through the ROS packages developed by Fraunhofer IPA (github.com/ipa320) and experience some issues with the joint configuration.

After running the setup assistant and following the instructions in the Industrial Robot Simulator tutorial, I get a configuration which works fine with the simulator. But if I then try to use the IPA packages by launching the respective packages instead of the simulator, I continuously get the following messages:

```
[ERROR] [1369212664.452440575]: Joint 'arm_controller' not found in model 'powerball'
[ERROR] [1369212664.452510068]: Joint '' not found in model 'powerball'
[ERROR] [1369212664.452566988]: Joint '' not found in model 'powerball'
[ERROR] [1369212664.452616925]: Joint '' not found in model 'powerball'
[ERROR] [1369212664.452665534]: Joint '' not found in model 'powerball'
[ERROR] [1369212664.452718125]: Joint '' not found in model 'powerball'
```

I have configured the joint names as "arm_X_joint" as required by the robot's URDF description. The robot's topics use the namespace "/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" instead of "/joint_trajectory_action", but I've configured this in the controllers.yaml file like written in the tutorial.

Here are some of my launch files and the controller/joint configuration:

**moveit_planning_execution_sim.launch** (this one works fine):

```
<launch>
 # The planning and execution components of MoveIt! configured to run
 # using a simulated ROS-Industrial node
 
 #-------------------------------------
 # These actions are normally handled in the "real" robot's bringup launch file
 #
 # load the URDF
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find schunk_hardware_config)/powerball/urdf/powerball.urdf.xacro'" />
 # run the robot simulator and action interface nodes
 <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
 
 # publish the robot state (tf transforms)
 <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
 #-------------------------------------
 
 <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/move_group.launch">
  <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
 </include>
 
 <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
 
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find powerball_moveit)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>
 
</launch>
```

**moveit_planning_execution_real.launch** (this one does not work):

```
<launch>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find schunk_hardware_config)/powerball/urdf/powerball.urdf.xacro'" />
 <include file="$(find schunk_bringup)/components/powerball_solo.launch" />
 
 <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/move_group.launch">
  <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
 </include>
 
 <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
 
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find powerball_moveit)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>
 
</launch>
```

**controllers.yaml**:

```
controller_manager_ns: pr2_controller_manager
controller_list:
  - name: "arm_controller"
    ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
     - arm_0_joint
      - arm_1_joint
      - arm_2_joint
      - arm_3_joint
      - arm_4_joint
      - arm_5_joint
      - arm_6_joint
```

**joint_names.yaml**:

```
controller_joint_names: ['arm_1_joint', 'arm_2_joint', 'arm_3_joint', 'arm_4_joint', 'arm_5_joint', 'arm_6_joint']
```

Now I'm really a bit out of ideas. Does anybody have an idea where this obviously wrong joint configuration might come from? Has anybody worked on the integration of the Powerball into MoveIt yet?

I know that this might be a little stumbling in the dark if someone hasn't worked with the IPA ROS packages before, but maybe you can give me a hint where I could continue debugging. If necessary, I can provide you with some more of my launch or configuration files.

Thank you, best regards,

Tobi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63201/joint-configuration-issues-with-schunk-powerball-moveit-integration/) by [jir-tobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4947/jir-tobi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Make sure that the urdf for the
   MoveIt Assistant was created out of
   schunk_hardware_config/powerball/urdf/powerball.urdf.xacro
2. Try this launch file:

   I just took
   `schunk_bringup/components/powerball_solo.launch`
   and put it into your
   `moveit_planning_execution_real.launch`
   but I commented out the "upload
   joint configuration" part.(It uploads
   `schunk_default_config/config/powerball_joint_configurations.yaml`
   to the parameter server. But this
   yaml has a different joint config.
   And MoveIt already does this for
   you.)

   ```
   <!-- upload robot_description -->
           <include file="$(find schunk_hardware_config)/powerball/urdf/upload_powerball.launch" />

   <!-- start robot_state_publisher -->
   <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher"/>

   <!-- upload joint configuration 
   <include file="$(find schunk_default_config)/launch/upload_param_powerball.launch" /> -->

   <!-- start arm  -->
   <include file="$(find schunk_bringup)/components/powerball.launch" />


   <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/move_group.launch">
   <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
   </include>

   <include file="$(find powerball_moveit)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>

   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find powerball_moveit)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>
   ```
3. Check your `controllers.yaml`
   formatting.
4. If this doesn't work recursively check all launch files called by powerball.launch for parameter server uploads (yaml files) you don't need.
5. Can you post your
   moveit_controller_manager.launch.

   Make sure you have disabled the
   controller_manager.

My **moveit_controller_manager.launch**

```
<launch>
  <arg name="moveit_controller_manager"
       default="pr2_moveit_controller_manager/Pr2MoveItControllerManager"/>
  <param name="moveit_controller_manager"
         value="$(arg moveit_controller_manager)"/>

  <arg name="controller_manager_name"
       default="pr2_controller_manager" />
  <param name="controller_manager_name"
         value="$(arg controller_manager_name)"/>

  <arg name="use_controller_manager" default="false" />
  <param name="use_controller_manager"
         value="$(arg use_controller_manager)" />

  <rosparam file="$(find kurtana_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>
</launch>
```

My **controllers.yaml**

```
 controller_manager_ns:
    pr2_controller_manager
    controller_list:
      - name: "katana_arm_controller"
        ns: follow_joint_trajectory
        default: true
        joints:
           - katana_motor1_pan_joint
           - katana_motor2_lift_joint
           - katana_motor3_lift_joint
           - katana_motor4_lift_joint
           - katana_motor5_wrist_roll_joint
```

In your error message the joint
"arm_controller" is not found.
Somehow the controller name
definition is parsed as a joint
definition. You could try another
name in your controllers.yaml and
check how the error changes. Perhaps
just make a completely new
controllers.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jir-tobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4947/jir-tobi/) on 2013-05-23**:
Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work although I've tried all your suggestions. Everywhere joint names appear, they are in the format arm_X_joint. I've also checked /arm_controller/joint_names and /controller_joint_names at runtime, they seem to be set correctly. Any other ideas?

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2013-05-23**:
One last guess: in schunk_hardware_config/powerball/config/powerball_trajectory_controller.yaml the joint index starts with 1. In your controllers.yaml in starts with 0. Same for schunk_default_config /config/ powerball_joint_configurations.yaml. Please check new 5. in my answer.

**Comment by [jir-tobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4947/jir-tobi/) on 2013-05-28**:
So indeed I had to remove arm_0_joint. But the actual error was located somewhere different, that is, there was a bug in the ipa_canopen package which made these messages appear. I've fixed it and reported it back to the IPA people. Thanks a lot for your help!